# Synology NAS 3 HDDs corrupted

Tags: network-attached-storage

Its the first time I am interacting with NAS.

In our NAS Server we have 5 hard disks and three out of five are now corrupted. Do we need to buy 5 new HDDs or we can buy 3 HDDs and used the old two Hard disks with the new ones.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know they are corrupted?  What corrupted them?

Comment: I tried to access them via web interface and over there i see the HDDs status is corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 5 matching drives. So either get 3 new ones that are the same size as the old ones, or buy 5 all new drives of the same size. It will work with mixed drives, but probably not the way you want.